# Subprocess for gathering incrementing CSV data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, subprocess

I am trying to write a script that is built around an existing script provided for me from a different team. I'm trying to use it with subprocess.

The script provided to me does the following things;

1. establishes a TCP connection to the target_ip
2. takes username and password for auth to application
3. Gathers listed metrics from the application on the ip, depending on your args
4. returns to stdout CSV formatted data of those metrics for the -u time interval

Due to how this provided script is constructed, it is meant to be run from the command line, and arguments are used to specify what you are wanting to collect. The CLI command looks like this:

```
./applicationAPI.py -target_ip -username -password metric1 metric2 metric3 -u 60
```

The `-u 60` is specifying the gather time interval to be every 60 seconds.

So in my script, I'm executing that through subprocess, shown like the following:

```py
import subprocess
import csv
import json

api_call = subprocess.run(['./applicationAPI.py'], '-target_ip', '-username', 
'-password', 'metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3', '-u', '60'], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)

api_response = (api_call.stdout)
f = StringIO(api_response)
reader = csv.reader(f)
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

I tried to do it this way, but the cursor just keeps hanging after execute until I <kbd>^C</kbd>.

I think that because the `applicationAPI` process keeps actively running over the established TCP connection, it is streaming data for every `-u` time interval, and doesn't 'finish' its execute, which is what the `api_call.stdout` is expecting.

Even though, if I run the provided script from the CLI normally, with the proper args, it then outputs to the terminal CSV results of the application metrics.

I would just normally use this, but I'm doing this script setup to parse all the CSV results to JSON for a different use case.

So I guess TLDR, how can subprocess handle streamed data within your python script?
Still trying to look up solution (Popen?) not sure but still looking.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra bracket in your subprocess command (subprocess.run([],,,,,,,,]) should be subprocess.run([,,,,,,,,]) ), not sure if this is your issue or not, as you probably would get an error if you ran it like that. Assuming this isn't your issue, my next suggestion is to include the `shell=True` argument since it is working on the CLI and not in your program. If that doesn't work, an alternative to subprocess is the os.popen() call, which I find to be a bit more usable when looking at output of the program.

Comment: Hi, yes so the extra bracket is typo. Any error in the syntax gives traceback. I believe that popen is what i'll have to try, as after researching some more, the process I am calling is a live connection, so process that doesnt give a return code because its still running

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.
The script that was given to me applicationAPI.py already formatted the data with a CSV reader. So using subprocess.Popen with stdout.PIPE, I can iter through the rows with my own CSV reader.

Comment: why you would call the python code in another file using subprocess and not simply import it into your own code and run it as any other function is beyond me. At least you could provide the code you have used in your solution.